# Use TFSBuild.proj with RTC?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, rtc, jazz

I'm currently trying to migrate an application from Microsoft's TFS to IBM's Rational Team Concert (RTC). The application is currently being built using MSBuild through TeamBuild in TFS with the TFSBuild.proj file. I'm wondering if it's possible to use this file for builds in RTC? I can build the project by specifying the Visual Studio solution file (*.sln), but I'd like to do it by reusing TFSBuild.proj file if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround to this. It seems that the Jazz Build Engine tries to invoke a target named "Build", regardless of if I pass in a *.sln or *.proj file. So in order to get RTC to work with my TFSBuild.proj file, I just added a target called "Build" to it which calls the proper entry point.

Comment: Also, apparently RTC 4.0 is supposed to support *.proj files. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with 3.0 for now.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem possible, at least not natively.

And the jazz.net website doesn't mentioned once the Tfsbuild.proj file, not in its manual or its forum section.

I have always seen builds launched from the solution file,  and not from a TFS file.